# Multitouch script (using xinput) no longer working

Tags: multi-touch

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# list of synaptics device properties http://www.x.org/archive/X11R7.5/doc/man/man4/synaptics.4.html#sect4
# list  current synaptics device properties: xinput list-props '"SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad"'
#
sleep 5 #added delay...
xinput set-int-prop "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad" "Device Enabled" 8 1
xinput --set-prop --type=int --format=32 "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad" "Synaptics Two-Finger Pressure" 4
xinput --set-prop --type=int --format=32 "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad" "Synaptics Two-Finger Width" 9         #  Below width 1 finger touch, above width simulate 2 finger touch. - value=pad-pixels
xinput --set-prop --type=int --format=8  "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad" "Synaptics Edge Scrolling" 1 1 0       #  vertical, horizontal, corner - values: 0=disable  1=enable
xinput --set-prop --type=int --format=32 "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad" "Synaptics Jumpy Cursor Threshold" 250 #  stabilize 2 finger actions - value=pad-pixels
#xinput --set-prop --type=int --format=8  "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad" "Synaptics Tap Action" 0 0 0 0 1 2 3   # pad corners rt rb lt lb tap fingers 1 2 3 (can't simulate more then 2 tap fingers AFAIK) - values: 0=disable 1=left 2=middle 3=right etc. (in FF 8=back 9=forward)
xinput --set-prop --type=int --format=8  "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad" "Synaptics Two-Finger Scrolling" 1 0   #  vertical scrolling, horizontal scrolling - values: 0=disable 1=enable
#xinput --set-prop --type=int --format=8  "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad" "Synaptics Circular Scrolling" 1
#xinput --set-prop --type=int --format=8  "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad" "Synaptics Circular Scrolling Trigger" 3
```

Hello everybody...
The above script allowed me to use happily multitouch for a month...
Now if I do a two fingers scrolling the mouse cursor just runs on the screen like possessed...
Any hints?

Comment: Kernel Update, maybe?

Comment: I'm already to the latest version but I've find the solution! Read below :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took me AGES but I'm really glad to share the solution.

On this page: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/308191/+index?comments=all

you can find comment 116 where with a click you download and then install this:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/308191/+attachment/1735234/+files/synaptics-dkms_1.0.0_all.deb

After installing just go to

System ---> Preferences ---> Mouse

Then click on Touchpad tab

and finally click on Two fingers scrolling.

YAY! :D